# Does the Addition Assignment Operator work when adding CSS styles in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I tried to add `"1fr "` to a DOM element’s style many times using a `for` loop and the `"+="` operator, but it only applied once, no matter how many times I ran the loop. So, I would like to know why it behaves this way. Here’s a little bit of my code.

```js
for (i = 1; i <= number; i++){
  sketchPadElement.style.gridTemplateColumns += "1fr ";
}
```

Since, I couldn’t get it to work, I wrote a function to repeat the string and used that to generate as many `"1fr "`s as I needed in one string like so.

```js
function makeGrid(number) {
  sketchPadElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = repeatString("1fr ", number);
}
```

And that works fine, but I’d still love to know why my previous attempt failed.

Comment: Have you tried `+= " 1fr"`?

Comment: There’s [`"1fr ".repeat(number)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). And there’s [`"repeat(`…`, 1fr)"`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/repeat\(\)). You could use [Custom properties](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). Your loop should work fine, though. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: Use `let i` in the beginning of `for` loop unless it's declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When assigning the string, any trailing space is automatically removed. So instead of using trailing space, use leading space:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++){
  sketchPadElement.style.gridTemplateColumns += " 1fr";
}
```

But instead of looping, it's better to outright use the `repeat()` CSS function:

```js
sketchPadElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It solves my problem perfectly.
I'll read on the repeat function.
Oh, I'd like to ask tho, is the trailing space removal a JavaScript thing?

Comment: Not in general, it's just how the setter for style properties works.